# Отображение fieldsets и tabularinline в django

Tags: python-3.x, django-admin, django-model

```
#admin.py
from .models import *
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(BookInstance)
class BookInstanceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('status', 'due_back', 'book')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('book','imprint', 'id')
        }),
        ('Availability', {
            'fields': ('status', 'due_back')
        }),
    )

class BooksInstanceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BookInstance
    fk_name = 'book'

class BooksInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Book
    fk_name = 'author'

@admin.register(Book)
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'display_genre')
    inlines = [BooksInstanceInline]

@admin.register(Author)
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'date_of_birth', 'date_of_death')
     fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', ('date_of_birth', 'date_of_death')]
     inlines = [BooksInline]

@admin.register(Genre)
class GenreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

#models.py
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db import models
import uuid

class Genre(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing a book genre (e.g. Science Fiction, Non Fiction).
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,help_text='Enter a book genre (e.g. Science Fiction, French Poetry etc.)')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing an author
    """
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField('Died', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', args[str(self.id)])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.last_name} {self.first_name}'

class Book(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing a book (but not a specific copy of a book).
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text='Enter a brief description of the book')
    isbn = models.CharField('ISBN',max_length=13,help_text='13 Character <a href="https://www.isbn-international.org/content/what-isbn">ISBN number</a>')
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, help_text='Select a genre for this book')

    LANGUAGE = (
            ('ru', 'Russian'),
            ('en', 'English'),
            ('ger', 'German'),
            ('fr', 'French'),
        )
    lang = models.CharField('Language',max_length=3,choices=LANGUAGE, default='ru', help_text='Language of book')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def display_genre(self):
        """
        Creates a string for the Genre. This is required to display genre in Admin.
        """
        return ', '.join([ genre.name for genre in self.genre.all()[:3] ])
        display_genre.short_description = 'Genre'

class BookInstance(models.Model):
    """
    Model representing a specific copy of a book (i.e. that can be borrowed from the library).
    """
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,help_text='Unique ID for this particular book across whole library')
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)

    LOAN_STATUS = (
            ('m', 'Maintenance'),
            ('o', 'On loan'),
            ('a', 'Avaible'),
            ('r', 'reserved'),
        )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LOAN_STATUS,blank=True, default='m',help_text='Book avaibility')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["due_back"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id} {self.book.title}'

    def title(self):
        return self.book.title
```

Django ошибок не выдает, по его мнению все в порядке. Но. Ох уж это "Но".
Шел я по шпаргалке mdn по django и натолкнулся на не рабочий код.
Проблема первая случилась с Fieldsets. они просто не работают(сейчас для затычки вставил list_display, без него он вместо сета выдает то что прописано в **str**). в чем проблема я не вижу.
Проблема вторая - tabularinline. По задумке мдн на страницах автора должны отобразиться его книги, а на странице книги должны отобразиться экземпляры этой книги. Однако и там и тут почему-то после связанных объектов(и даже если их нет) отображаются три не созданных объекта.
И так вопрос. Что это и как с этим бороться?